# How to query a list of all the different errors?

Tags: sql-server-2008-r2, performance, query-performance

I have a DB which is very big and stores a lot of eventlogs, around 15 million rows.
When I try this query, it is totally impossible to get some results.

Any idea how I could do this? Maybe indexed views?

(BTW.: the question is just about the performance problem. Apart from that the query is working if there are much less entries.)

```
SELECT dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
    ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
    ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
    ,dbo.Sources.Source
    ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
    ,dbo.Main.Msg
FROM dbo.EntryTypes
INNER JOIN dbo.Main ON dbo.EntryTypes.pk_EntryType = dbo.Main.fk_EntryType
INNER JOIN dbo.EventIds ON dbo.EventIds.pk_EventId = dbo.Main.fk_EventId
INNER JOIN dbo.LogNames ON dbo.LogNames.pk_LogName = dbo.Main.fk_LogName
INNER JOIN dbo.Servers ON dbo.Servers.pk_Server = dbo.Main.fk_Server
INNER JOIN dbo.Sources ON dbo.Sources.pk_Source = dbo.Main.fk_Source
WHERE dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType = 'Error'
GROUP BY dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
    ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
    ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
    ,dbo.Sources.Source
    ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
    ,dbo.Main.Msg
ORDER BY dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType
    ,dbo.Servers.SERVER
    ,dbo.LogNames.LogName
    ,dbo.Sources.Source
    ,dbo.EventIds.EventId
    ,dbo.Main.Msg
```

The tables:

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[EntryTypes](
    [pk_EntryType] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [EntryType] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_EntryTypes] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_EntryType] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[LogNames](
    [pk_LogName] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [LogName] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_LogNames] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_LogName] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Sources](
    [pk_Source] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Source] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Sources] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_Source] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Servers](
    [pk_Server] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Server] [nvarchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Servers] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_Server] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Main](
    [pk_Main] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [EventId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Id] [bigint] NOT NULL,
    [Msg] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [Indx] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_Server] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_Source] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_LogName] [int] NOT NULL,
    [fk_EntryType] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Main] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_Main] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]


CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Errors](
    [pk_Error] [int] IDENTITY(1,1) NOT NULL,
    [Time] [datetime] NOT NULL,
    [ErrorMsg] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [ErrorMsgFull] [ntext] NOT NULL,
    [fk_Server] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Errors] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [pk_Error] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX  = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE  = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS  = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS  = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY] TEXTIMAGE_ON [PRIMARY]







ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Errors]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Errors_Servers] FOREIGN KEY([fk_Server])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Servers] ([pk_Server])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Errors] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Errors_Servers]



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_EntryTypes] FOREIGN KEY([fk_EntryType])
REFERENCES [dbo].[EntryTypes] ([pk_EntryType])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_EntryTypes]



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_LogNames] FOREIGN KEY([fk_LogName])
REFERENCES [dbo].[LogNames] ([pk_LogName])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_LogNames]



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Servers] FOREIGN KEY([fk_Server])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Servers] ([pk_Server])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Servers]



ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main]  WITH CHECK ADD  CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Sources] FOREIGN KEY([fk_Source])
REFERENCES [dbo].[Sources] ([pk_Source])

ALTER TABLE [dbo].[Main] CHECK CONSTRAINT [FK_Main_Sources]
```

Comment: Maybe just the proper indexes are needed. Could you show the indexes that you have to support this query?

Comment: 15 million rows really isn't that large for sql server.  I'm thinking the same thing RLF is thinking, indexing may not be as optimized as it should be.

Comment: Yes, this is possible. ;) I never worked before with such "big" DBs...
Because of that I'm asking here what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: I would group by the 5 FKs plus the `Main.Msg` and add a composite index on these 6 columns.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!
Now I get the results in a, for me, acceptable time (+- 100 Seconds for about 1 500 000 lines).
I added a non-unique, non-clustered index for every FK and also a composite index with the fields which I use in my query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just looking at your definitions (thank you very much for that) I see:

1. No index on to support `WHERE  dbo.EntryTypes.EntryType = 'Error'`. (But this may not be needed if it is a small table with just a few entries.)
2. Your `fk_*` columns in `MAIN` have check constraints, but no indexes.  You should create some indexes since they are used to join to several different tables on their  existing primary keys.

This does not necessary imply that every `fk_*` column needs an index, but you can try creating a few indexes on those columns and see how much that helps.

Note: ypercube recommends a composite index in his comments on the question.

Comment: Ok, thank you very much!
Now I get the results in a, for me, acceptable time (+- 100 Seconds for about 1 500 000 lines).
I added a non-unique, non-clustered index for every FK and also a composite index with the fields which I use in my query.